# Find Member in a List of Objects [error TS1005: ':' expected]

Tags: angular

I have a like component which as input parameters gets the number of likes and boolean value if current User liked that comment or not:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-like',
  template: `
    <i
      class="fa fa-heart mr-1"
      [class.highlighted]="iLike"
      (click)="onClick()">
    </i>
    <span>{{ totalLikes }}</span>
  `
})

export class LikeeComponent {
  @Input() iLike = false;
  @Input() totalLikes = 0;
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter();

  onClick() {
      ...
  }

}
```

which I added to post component:

```
post.component.html

<app-like [totalLikes]="comment.likes?.length" [iLike]="isUserLikeComment(comment)"></app-like>
```

Also, from WEB Api Endpoint I got something like this as comment object:

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
        "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium",
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Glenna Reichert",
            "userName": "Delphine",
            "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
            "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
            "photo": "b9d5bd7b-24c7-4e45-8f30-5c8740050cdf.jpg",
            "address": null
        },
        "likes": [
            {
                "commentId": 1,
                "userId": 1
            },
            {
                "commentId": 1,
                "userId": 2
            },
            {
                "commentId": 1,
                "userId": 3
            }
        ]
    }
```

The totalLikes part in like component works fine `[totalLikes]="comment.likes?.length` but the second part `[iLike]="isUserLikeComment(comment)"` not.

here is the implementation of the `isUserLikeComment(comment)`

```
posts.component.ts

 isUserLikeComment(comment: Comment) {
    let data = comment.likes?.find(ob => ob.userId === 1);

    if (data != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

The error is in this line:

```
let data = comment.likes?.find(ob => ob.userId === 1);

error TS1005: ':' expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let data = comment.likes?.find(ob => ob.userId === 1);
```

indicates the use of the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). You could try something like:

```
if (comment.likes) {
  const data = comment.likes.find(ob => ob.userId === 1);

  if (data) {
    // like with userId found
  } else {
    // like with userId not found
  }
} else {
  // no likes
}
```

Comment: Yes. That is it. I was confused with the error message. Usually they are more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript optional chaining [operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) allows 3 types of accesses:

1. optional property access (`prop1?.prop2?.prop3`)
2. optional element access (`arr?.[0]`)
3. optional call (`` log?.(`Request finished at at ${new Date().toISOString()}\`); ``)

None of them support optional chaining to a JS method (`find` here). So the usage of `?.` operator doesn't trigger the optional chaining, but possibly a ternary operator. Depending on the TS version, you might also receive `Expression expected` error. So it mustn't be used here. The statement should be

```js
let data = comment.likes?.find(ob => ob.userId === 1);
```